# multiple if statements in a mysql query not responding correctly

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table in a mysql database that has eight colums.
Brand, Type , Description, Size, Tread, Stock, Price, Pics.
The if statement that I use below works well.

```
if($brandname=="Any Brand" && $pickchecker=="Single" ){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tirestock WHERE Size='$picked' AND Description='$pickcheck' AND Stock IN('1','3')";
```

When I add an elseif statement to it the second statement doesn't work it returns no stock records even though there is stock of pairs.

```
if($brandname=="Any Brand" && $pickchecker=="Single" ){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tirestock WHERE Size='$picked' AND Description='$pickcheck' AND Stock IN('1','3')";
}   
elseif ($brandname=="Any Brand" && $pickchecker=="Pair"){

    $query = "Select * FROM tirestock WHERE Brand='$brandname' AND Size='$picked' AND Description='$pickcheck' AND Stock='2'";
}
```

What am I not doing right and why does this not working? This comes from a php script to query the database when the user picks a radio button $pickchecker for singles or pairs.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are `$brandname` and `$pickchecker` set to? If `$brandname` _isn't_ "Any Brand", then neither statement will run. If it _is_ "Any Brand", then you're looking for "Any Brand" in the brand field in your table.

Comment: $brandname is set to Any Brand this is what the user chooses. $pickchecker is set to either single of pairs depending also what the user chooses. I want the query to run the first if statement if the user chooses single and the second elseif if the user chooses Pair.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to remove the `Brand='$brandname' AND` from the second query. It doesn't appear in the first, and since you're searching for the literal string "Any Brand" I don't think you'll get any results.

*Answer based on @andrewsi's comment*